# how to render multiple highcharts into one div tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

i want to create a highchart program,where i need to incorporate various highcharts.one drop down would be there with options listed in it.and those option should be the name of different different highcharts.eg.gauge highvhart,pie highchart,bar ,column,sparkline,line highchart.and a single div tag should be there on the same page.If i select gauge highchart option from the dropdown list then gauge  highchart should be displayed on the page.

I know how to create these highcharts separately but m not getting any idea regarding the issue where we should use only one div tag to render all the highcharts based on the selected option from the dropdown box.

I'am not giving my code because i've no idea about this.so,please suggest me some idea.thanks in advance.

here's my complete code .In this code data is displayed in a tabular format but i want to have this in a dropdown manner which i have explained before and i just want one div tag to render all the highcharts based on the selection made.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
         <style type="text/css">

table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
th{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
thead th{
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}
td{
    padding:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


         </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'area',
        margin:[0,0,0,0],
        //borderWidth:1
    },
    title:{
        text:''
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        maxPadding:0,
        minPadding:0,
        endOnTick:false,
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled:false
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled:false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series:{
            lineWidth:1,
            shadow:false,
            states:{
                hover:{
                    lineWidth:9
                }
            },
            marker:{
                //enabled:false,
                radius:1,
                states:{
                    hover:{
                        radius:2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        color:'#666',
        fillColor:'rgba(204,204,204,.25)',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }]
});
});

$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container1',
        defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
        margin:[0,0,0,0],
        //borderWidth:1
    },
    title:{
        text:''
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        maxPadding:0,
        minPadding:0,
        endOnTick:false,
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled:false
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled:false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series:{
            lineWidth:1,
            shadow:false,
            states:{
                hover:{
                    lineWidth:9
                }
            },
            marker:{
                //enabled:false,
                radius:1,
                states:{
                    hover:{
                        radius:2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        color:'#666',
        fillColor:'rgba(204,204,204,.25)',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }]
});
});


$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2',
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
        margin:[0,0,0,0],
        //borderWidth:1
    },
    title:{
        text:''
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        maxPadding:0,
        minPadding:0,
        endOnTick:false,
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled:false
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled:false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series:{
            lineWidth:1,
            shadow:false,
            states:{
                hover:{
                    lineWidth:9
                }
            },
            marker:{
                //enabled:false,
                radius:1,
                states:{
                    hover:{
                        radius:2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        color:'#666',
        fillColor:'rgba(204,204,204,.25)',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }]
});
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<table>
    <caption>Sparkline</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Value</th>    
            <th>Trend</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Category 1</th>
            <td>54.4</td>
            <td><div id="container" style="height:60px;width:200px;"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Category 2</th>
            <td>60.4</td>
            <td><div id="container1" style="height:60px;width:200px;"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Category 3</th>
            <td>60.4</td>
            <td><div id="container2" style="height:80px;width:300px;"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you simply destroy the previous chart control and build a new one when the selection changes?

Comment: No source code = nothing to work with. How can we tell you to put these charts together without having the source for them to see how they function? I'm not sure how you expect anyone to answer your question. To display your source code you can paste it into the question, select/highlight it and press CTRL + K for windows users.

Comment: I think that functions (addSeries / series.update / point.update etc) from [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) help you manipulate data.

Comment: I've posted my complete code .In this code data is displayed in a tabular format but i want to have this in a dropdown manner which i have explained before..@NewToJS

Comment: Nate thanks for the reply..but can u please tellme what changes i need to do in my code.i  have posted my code here.i got your concept but how to do this..@Nate Barbettini

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this would work

http://jsfiddle.net/4b0uyd2d/1/

```
var value = 3; // Here you have to set value that you get from database
    var $select = $('.js-select'); // Specify your select here

    var updateBoxes = function( value ) {
        $('.js-box').hide();
        $('#container' + value).show();
    }

    var initSelects = function( value ) {
        if (value !== 0) {
            $select.val( value );
        }
        $select.on('change', function() {
            updateBoxes( $select.val() );
        });
    }

    initSelects( value );
    updateBoxes( value );
```

Add this code below your existing highchart functions.